# What does "relax" do in scipy integrators

Tags: python, scipy

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.integrate.html#scipy.integrate.ode.integrate) for `scipy.integrate.ode.integrate` does not describe what the `relax` parameter does. What does it do? Opening the source reveals that it is a Boolean flag, but that all I get.

Comment: Set it to ´True´ once you stop caring about what its value should be, otherwise the default is ´False´.

Comment: run: ```Integrate from t=t0 to t=t1 using y0 as an initial condition.Return 2-tuple (y1,t1)``` run_relax: ```Integrate from t=t0 to t>=t1 and return (y1,t)```

Comment: @sascha That is actually a cool feature. I'll accept that answer.

Comment: As i'm not too familiar with ode's, i won't make an answer out of this. This ist just a citation from ```scipy/integrate/_ode.py``` line 672. @J.J seems to be more experienced on why and when to use it!

Comment: In the [documentation of VODE](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/nsde/pubs/207532.pdf) (which is one of the integration methods available in Scipy) there is a technical paragraph (3.4) about **Linear System Relaxation For Stiff Systems**. I don't know if it has anything to do with this parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: This parameter only gives the method a permission to return a less precise answer. Keep it at default value False. It has nothing to do with relaxation of stiff systems.

**Long answer**: The [current version of documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.integrate.html#scipy.integrate.ode.integrate) explains this parameter as

> relax : bool
>   If True and if the integrator supports the run_relax method, then integrate until t_1 >= t and return. relax is not referenced if step=True. This parameter is provided in order to expose internals of the implementation, and should not be changed from its default value in most cases.

In English: `integrate` method takes a value `t` at which you want to evaluate the solution. But the integrator chooses step sizes on its own, and in general t will not be one of points it hits. How to deal with this?

- By default, the solution is computed up to some point t1 >= t, and then the value at t is computed by interpolation (between t1 and a preceding value).
- But if `relax=True`, the solution is computed up to some point t1 >= t and the value at t1 is returned. No interpolation is made.

Naturally, this means the method overshoots and returns a less accurate value, so it's not something you would want to accept as a final answer. It may be useful inside of a more sophisticated algorithm that implements its own interpolation, but it's hard to imagine how this could happen at SciPy level, because t1 is not returned.

Example: integrating y' = y with y(0)=1. Exact solution is y = exp(t). Compare the exact solution and two approximations computed at t = 0.1:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
r = ode(lambda t, y: y).set_integrator('vode').set_initial_value(1, 0)
print(np.exp(0.1), r.integrate(0.1), r.integrate(0.1, relax=True))
```

Output:

```
 1.10517091808    1.10517178     1.10959337
```

With relax=True the overshoot is very visible.